# Building BizTalk 2009 projects on TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, biztalk, biztalk-2009

I am trying to get a biztalk 2009 project to build on TFS 2010, and i keep running into this same error.

```
 C:\BuildsShare\....\Schema\ShippingConfirmation.xsd: Could not find file 'Microsoft.BizTalk.TOM.resources'.
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161184/biztalk-2009-projects-not-playing-well-with-tfs-2010-beta-2-automated-build) post, it resolved some of my build problems but not all, specifically I haven not seen any reference to 'Microsoft.BizTalk.TOM.resources'. The assembly is called Microsoft.BizTalk.TOM.dll, I have tried GACing it. I have tried not referencing specific versions. I have tried explicitly referencing it. None changes the error. What is maddening is that it builds in Visual Studio on the same box, it build using both msbuild 3.5 and msbuild 4, from the same build directory that tfs is using.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building the entire solution, try building individual projects.  Sometimes this will solve the type of issue you're seeing.

Comment: Weird, that worked. It must be some sort of bug with BizTalk and/or TFS 2010. Thanks.